# Create a dynamic banded rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to know how to make a dynamic banded rows in a table which switches color once the date changes like shown here :

Left figure would be what I want to do, Right figure is what I can use if left isn't possible:

[image: Left figure would be what I want to do, Right figure is what I can use if left isn't possible.]

I have been doing this manually for a month now but I'd like to know if it were possible to do it automatically?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use a formula-based conditional formatting rule to set the font to white if the cell above has the same date.

Comment: @ExcelHero When I put in a new date, lets say I have A, B and C on 01/01 then it would start of with a grey fill, next day I add in D on 02/01 then it fills the line to white, then I add E on 03/01 it fills the line to grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution here, thank you Tim Williams for guiding me to search for a conditional formatting rule! It works wonders.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2661-excel-alternate-row-color-based-on-group.html

I used specifically the formula in column E =IF(OR(A3=A2,ISBLANK(A3)),IF(ISBLANK(B3),0,E2),E2+1) and conditional formatting =ISODD($E3) to make [this result possible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxGxl.png)